# Why does CGAffineTransform(Rotate) work differently for UIBezierCurve and UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform

I’m using a drawingView which is simply a VC’s view to draw a rectangle that rotates depending on a pan gesture. I apply 3 transforms on it. I translate the rectangle half it’s width left to put the top center of the rectangle at 0,0; rotate it some multiple of 45º and then translate it to the position of the gesture begin. This works perfectly.

When the pan gesture ends I want to drop an image view of the same size exactly where the rectangle is. The code for the drawing view are the save as the VC with the exception that in the drawing view the `CGAffineTransform` is applied to the path

```swift
  func addImageView(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ direction: Direction) {
    let myImageView = MyImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 116, height: 200))
    myImageView = UIColor.systemBlue

    var viewTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    viewTransform = viewTransform.translatedBy(x: -58, y: 0)

    var angle: CGFloat?
    let pi = CGFloat.pi

    switch direction {
    case .up:
      angle = 0
    case .upRight:
      angle = pi / 4.0
    case .right:
      angle = pi / 2.0
    case .downRight:
      angle = 3 * pi / 4.0
    case .down:
      angle = pi
    case .downLeft:
      angle = 5 * pi / 4.0
    case .left:
      angle = 3 * pi / 2.0
    case .upLeft:
      angle = 7 * pi / 4.0
    default:
      angle = nil
    }

    if angle != nil {
      viewTransform = viewTransform.rotated(by: angle!)
    }

    viewTransform = viewTransform.translatedBy(x: x, y: y)
    myImageView = viewTransform
    view.addSubview(myImageView)
    print("myImageView: \(myImageView)")
  }
```

If there is no rotation the imageView drops perfectly. If there is rotation it (in all
but one case) vanishes off the screen. In one case it basically draws (at the correct angle) but in a very wrong position.

I’m not sure what the image view is rotating “About” and have had no luck tracking down the correct mathematical changes.

**Edit:** When doing just the initial translate and the rotation; everything is fine and the UIImage rotates around the center of the frame. When I then add a translate after the rotation; it changes the point around which the view rotates making a bigger circle.

So the problem is moving the rotated view into place after the rotation is done.

[image: Drawing UIBezierCurve works fine]
[image: UIImageView is off course]

Drawing code for drawing view

```swift
class DraggingView: UIView {

  var currVector:(origin: CGPoint, direction: Direction)?

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      guard currVector != nil else {
        return
      }

      let drawRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                    width: 116, height: 200)

      let drawPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: drawRect, cornerRadius: 10.0)
      drawPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -58, y: 0))

      var transform: CGAffineTransform?
      let pi = 3.1415927

      switch currVector!.direction {
      case .downLeft:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: pi / 4.0)
      case .downRight:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -pi / 4.0)
      case .left:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: pi / 2.0)
      case .right:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -pi / 2.0)
      case .up:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: pi)
      case .upLeft:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3 * pi / 4.0)
      case .upRight:
        transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -3 * pi / 4.0)
      default:
        transform = nil
      }

      if transform != nil {
        drawPath.apply(transform!)
      }
      drawPath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: currVector!.origin.x, y: currVector!.origin.y))
      UIColor.label.setStroke()

      drawPath.stroke()
    }

  public func setVector(origin: CGPoint, direction: Direction) {
    currVector = (origin, direction)
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }

  public func clearVector() {
    currVector = nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the code that transforms the path? So that I know where you actually want the image to be located.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to translate the image view before rotating it? Rotation should be normally done around the center of the image view, and then the center of image view should be matched with the rectangle center

Comment: @Sweeper I added the draw code

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk The goal is to show a rectangle drawing following the finger from the top center of the card in the general direction the user is drawing. Once the user lifts their finger the image view will drop in that rectangle's place.

Comment: How about, rather than translating it -58 in the x direction, translate +100 in the y direction? I think it's because the `UIBezierPath.apply` uses a different anchor point than `UIView.transform`. `UIBezierPath.apply` uses (0, 0), but `UIView.transform` uses the view's center.

Comment: Try setting `myImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)`, then apply ONLY ROTATION transform to myImageView without any translations.

Comment: I'm now adding the view at the destination point, setting the anchor point as (x:0.0, y:0.5) and then doing the rotate. Down is working but everything else is drifting a little.

Comment: I tried creating a view, setting the frame, then attaching the translate and rotate to it by way of a slider. That works. I just can't replicate it in the code.

Comment: **Edit:** I fixed the angles in the VC's above source to rotate correctly in correspondence with the bezier paths. The rotation is pretty much spot on, the drift still exists.